# R fromJSON lexical error: invalid char in json text

Tags: r, jsonlite

I have this code that used to work, but today it gives me the following error.

```
fromJSON("http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/getJSON.aspx?type=win&date=2018-09-09&venue=ST&raceno=1")
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
lexical error: invalid char in json text. <HTML> <head> <script> Challeng
```

Any idea on what may have caused this? I also welcome any idea for which I can simply read the text on the link. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The url expires 1 day after the meeting (race date).  So to make it work you need a date in the future (say 1 day out) plus the relevant venue code ST or HV

The response you should get when it is expired is: {"OUT":""}